# What is the concept behind using "use" keyword in different context on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5, namespaces

I have two queries regarding the use of "use" keyword in php(laravel).

Below is a code excerpt from laravel docs:

```
use App\Flight;

$flights = App\Flight::all();

foreach ($flights as $flight) {
    echo $flight->name;
}
```

The code in line 1 allows us to use Flight model and line 2 has a statement which fetches all the records. So, in line 2 cannot we just say `Flight::all();` instead of `App\Flight::all();`. Are both correct and does it relate to relative and absolute path stuff?

Second Query(related to softDeletes):
Below is a code block from one of my models:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Post extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable = ['title','body'];
}
```

Here on line 6, the following statement is used:

```
use SoftDeletes;
```

Why are we again using use keyword with `softDeletes` because we didn't use that with model and simply we could do :

```
class Post extends Model
```

without the following code statement:

```
use Model;
```

in case of models.

Comment: first one is model and second is trait

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29001191/laravel-5-use-statements this link can help you for better understanding of use statement at the beginning of a file and use statement inside of class file is trait, for that see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Answer (score 5):

The `use` command in PHP is used to import/alias namespaces ([docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)).

First of all, you need to know that this command supports three types of importing/aliasing: classes, interfaces and namespaces.

Your first example is a class import:

```
use App\Flight;

$flights = Flight::all();

foreach ($flights as $flight) {
    echo $flight->name;
}
```

It basically imports the class `Flight` found inside the namespace `App`, so we assume that the class would start like this:

```
namespace App;

...

class Flight extends Model {...}
```

As an alternative you could just import the namespace and reference the class with the namespace it belongs to:

```
use App;

$flights = App\Flight::all();

foreach ($flights as $flight) {
    echo $flight->name;
}
```

Or you can avoid importing anything at all and use absolute references:

```
$flights = \App\Flight::all();

foreach ($flights as $flight) {
    echo $flight->name;
}
```

In your second example `SoftDeletes` is a [trait](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), which is similar to a class, but only intended to group functionality in a consistent way (in this case, all the methods needed to perform soft deletes).

The trait looks like this:

```
namespace Illuminate\Database\Eloquent;

trait SoftDeletes{...}
```

As you can see it follows the same logic as before: look in the namespace `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent` and use the class/trait `SoftDeletes` so I can reference it.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

1 - `use` used as importing `App\Flight` class. Following statements both are correct `Flight::all()` and `\App\Flight::all()` (The `\` in front is important, if you leave the `\` in front php will look for namespace from current namespace - relative).

2 - `use` used in the context of `Traits` [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). `SoftDeletes` is a trait & `Model` is a class.